# What kind of chemistry background to get to pursue computational chemistry from an IT background?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, education

What kind of chemistry background to get to pursue computational chemistry from an IT background?

I have no background in chemistry, and there might be others like me. But I know about computer models.

What kind of chemistry do I need to know in order to pursue computational chemistry models?

It's intuitive that getting a M.Sc. worth of chemistry on top of M.Sc. worth of IT is not effective. But possibly something that allows one to discuss with chemists and understand the problems that they hand to a data scientist.

Also, does computational chemistry mean that one ought to focus more on analytic chemistry or theoretical chemistry or that sorts?

What about reading only "Mathematical models of ..." types of resources?

Comment: I think, "computational chemistry" is a very broad term. I assume that computational approaches are used in all fields of chemistry. It may be a good idea to focus the question on a certain area of chemistry.

Comment: @GregorMichalicek Sounds reasonable, but I don't understand what such division to areas could be.

Comment: Do you want to run your own simulations, for example to do research in chemistry, or are you interested more in the software and just want to know what it's doing and why (perhaps to support users, or to optimise the software)?

Comment: @PhilHasnip The thing is that someone coming from just an IT background may have zero idea about what chemists are even looking for and what their theories are. Therefore I'm asking for ideas regarding how to mitigate this gap.

Comment: 1) What level of chemistry education have you had? High school? 1st year university? Also, **why** do you want to pursue computational chemistry. What do you want to accomplish or do?

Comment: @NikeDattani That is too detailed. The crucial bit s that a "CS perspective" can study things only using mathematical models. Therefore the chemistry background should support that more than being able to do experiments or something.

Comment: @mavavilj Why is it too detailed? Not telling us these details just makes it so much harder to write an answer. Almost everyone here knows what chemistry background is needed for the computational chemistry work that they do, yet this question has not had any answer for 6+ months. Based on my experience, this question would have a good answer if you provided those details. Are you asking because you want to pursue computational chemistry? Or because you know someone else that does?

Comment: @mavavilj Since you didn't ping me with the @ character, I didn't see your response.

Comment: @NikeDattani A company that might utilize a computational chemist would have different people tasked on doing experiments, and different people comparing that with simulations. Then I want to know what the people comparing with simulations need to know about chemistry experiments.

Comment: You seem to have deleted the comment before my most recent one, and after my 18 February one.